# gstreamer wrong colors when converting h264 to raw RGB

Tags: linux, colors, rgb, gstreamer

I have stream on one computer using this command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src do-timestamp=true ! video264,width=1296,height=730,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! gdppay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.116 port=5000
```

So the output is h264 in YU12 format. I need this format in raw RGB, so on receiver site I use:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=\(string\)RGB ! videoconvert !  fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=true
```

Which results in image with right colors, as you can see bellow:
[image: fpsdisplaysink is ok]

However when I pipe this output to other program, and I tried custom one which converts rgb frames to textures and also ffplay with parameter pix_fmt rgb24, the colors are wrong and the picture is shifted in some weird way.
[image: wrong colors with piped output]

What is weird is when I try bgr the red color was correct in second output the fdisplaysink one didn't change.

I am using `gst-launch-1.0 --version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.4.5
GStreamer 1.4.5`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the command you're using to pipe to ffplay?

Comment: @mpr gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,height=730,width=1296,framerate=25/1,format=RGB ! videoconvert ! filesink sync=false location=/dev/stdout | ffplay  -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 1296x730  -i -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments below: the **"-q"** option is needed to prevent gst-launch from spitting out debug info to the stdout pipe.

---

Ok, funny story, looks like when you specify video size in ffplay you use HEIGHTxWIDTH, and in GStreamer you use WIDTHxHEIGHT.  This command works fine:

> gst-launch-1.0 -q videotestsrc pattern=ball ! video/x-raw,height=320,width=240,framerate=30/1,format=RGB ! fdsink | ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24 -video_size 240x320 -i -

If the colors are shifted you probably have an RGB mixed up with a BGR somewhere.

You can get a list of all the ffplay pixel formats like this:

> ffplay -pix_fmts

And the GStreamer pixel formats that videoconvert supports are here:

> gst-inspect-1.0 videoconvert

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem, I can actually specify the sizes as parameters in videoconvert plugin, won't change a thing. And the pixel format is not a problem, both have specified the same. However I found the real problem, or better to say how to avoid my problem. WIll post update soon.

Comment: `-q` works like a charm in my use case, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out, it's some kind of pipeing problem. I am not sure why but pipeing via stdout to another program just shifts everything. It looks like the frames are starting on wrong byte or something. I even got to the point where the video was doing some moving picture effect where with each frame the picture was more shifted. It is not really a matter of used colorspace, it just happens to every single one.

I am not sure how to remove this problem, and this solution I am posting is not how to remove it rather than how to avoid it.

Stdout doesn't work correctly, but saving to file for instance does. So I tried using named pipe. Classic `mkfifo`. Doing something like this

`gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,height=730,width=1296,framerate=25/1,format=RGB ! videoconvert ! filesink sync=false location=pipe`

and than either opening the pipe, or simply redirecting it like

```
cat pipe | program -
```

makes it working like a charm. No colors wrong, no shifted picture.

I am not sure what is the difference between named pipes and stdout pipeing in linux (I simply never had enough time to study them), I just once read there is less overhead in named ones.

Comment: Did you try adding -q to the gstreamer command?  I noticed it was dumping some warning messages to stdout if I didn't include it.

Comment: ou, didn't notice that... that works like a charm, I am sorry I marked your answer as solution.